# SELECT my GUID into a variable using SQL Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, select, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that I want to store a GUID that I Select into a local variable for further use.  I am trying it as below (and with several other variations), but am getting a syntax error near '@myvars'...

```
DECLARE @myvars uniqueidentifier;
SELECT ID 
INTO @myvars
FROM Device
WHERE DeviceID=@DeviceID
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume you'll have one row only expected?

Comment: I was just thinking about that.  Mostly yes, but in the case that it isn't, will doing it the way below still work?

Comment: No, SQL Server would randomly assign one of the n rows. You'd use an OUTPUT clause into a table variable to capture all values in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
DECLARE @myvars uniqueidentifier --declare the local variable to store value in

SELECT @myvars=ID                --assign's the ID column into the variable
FROM Device
WHERE DeviceID=@DeviceID
```

quick test:

```
DECLARE @myvars uniqueidentifier --declare the local variable to store value in
declare @x table (id uniqueidentifier, valueOf varchar(4))

insert @x values (NEWID (),'aa')
insert @x values (NEWID (),'bb')
insert @x values (NEWID (),'cc')

SELECT @myvars=ID                --assign's the ID column into the variable
FROM @x
WHERE valueOf='bb'

SELECT @myvars
select * from @x
```

OUTPUT:

```
------------------------------------
36503FD9-A299-4DC5-A7BD-67605FF47ACE

(1 row(s) affected)

id                                   valueOf
------------------------------------ -------
175DCBF8-C418-4B5B-9270-66C12980D489 aa
36503FD9-A299-4DC5-A7BD-67605FF47ACE bb
E4F075FF-BA4B-4BB5-AD9F-ADB03FE88590 cc

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Even better. Works perfect! Thanks again.